# mvc website does not run on production server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an MVC website in vb.NET which runs perfectly well on the local server.
I have published it to a remote server using the Publish method of Visual Studio so I believe all the necessary files should be in place on the remote server. The web hosting service runs MVC 4 and 5. On running the page from the remote server the AngularJS code fails to find the VB controller.

In the AngularJS Service section the code is:

```
this.getPasswords = function () {
    return $http.get("api/passwords");
};
```

In the AngularJS controller section the  relevant code is:

```
getPasswords();
// get from passwordsController.vb
function getPasswords() {
    passwordService.getPasswords()
        .success(function (passwords) {
            $scope.passwords = passwords;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Error in getting passwords: ' + error.message;
        });
};
```

The VB controller code is:

```
' GET: api/passwords
Function Getpasswords() As IQueryable(Of password)
    Return db.passwords
End Function
```

The line:

```
return $http.get("api/passwords");
```

does not connect with the Getpasswords function in the VB controller.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask]. _"the AngularJS code fails"_ is not descriptive enough. Include the actual error message or whatever does happen, and show your research for that.

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's a URL issue. You're calling `api/passwords`, which will be relative to whatever basepath is in play. For example, if you're on a URL already, like `http://example.com/foo/bar`, then the URL you're actually requesting is `http://example.com/foo/bar/api/passwords`, which is almost certainly not correct. You should always use paths like `/api/passwords`. The preceding `/` causes the URL to be domain-relative, i.e. `http://example.com/api/passwords`.

Comment: The issue is resolved. As Chris Pratt suggested it was a path problem.